# I am trying to create a clean 5x5 grid without any brackets, quotes, or commas

Tags: python

The following is my code:

```
...
self.__treasure_map = size
self.__chest_positions = chests
self.__tree_positions = trees
self.__num_chests_found = 0

self.grid=[]

for i in range(self.__treasure_map):
    self.grid.append([])
    for j in range(self.__treasure_map):
        self.grid[i].append(TreasureMap.UNSEARCHED_CHAR)

def display_map(self):
    print('  ', end="")
    for i in range(self.__treasure_map):
        count = 0
        print(' ',count+i,end='')
    print('\n',end ='')
    for i in self.grid:
        self.grid[count][0] = count
        count+=1
        print(i)
```

This is my grid after printing out:

[image]

However, this is the outcome I want

[image]

Comment: self.grid is a list of lists. So you are printing the whole list itself (along with the closing brackets). You have to iterate through the list, and then print the elements inside the list with proper spacing like you in the first loop of the display function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I understand what you're trying to do, but your code is too complicated. It would really help if you made a [mre]. For example, what use is `count+i` is `count` is always 0?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may at least be close to what you want:

```
class TreasureMap:
    UNSEARCHED_CHAR = '.'


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, size, chests, trees):
        self.__treasure_map = size
        self.__chest_positions = chests
        self.__tree_positions = trees
        self.__num_chests_found = 0

        self.grid=[]
        for i in range(self.__treasure_map):
            self.grid.append([])
            for j in range(self.__treasure_map):
                self.grid[i].append(TreasureMap.UNSEARCHED_CHAR)

    def display_map(self):
        print('  ', ' '.join(str(i) for i in range(self.__treasure_map)))
        for i in range(self.__treasure_map):
            print('{:>2}'.format(i),  ' '.join(elem for elem in self.grid[i]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj = MyClass(5, 1, 2)
    obj.display_map()
```

Output:

```
   0 1 2 3 4
 0 . . . . .
 1 . . . . .
 2 . . . . .
 3 . . . . .
 4 . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your code, but here's a general way to get what you want. I'm using a list of strings as input instead of a list of lists because that guarantees all the grid cells will be exactly 1-long.

```
def print_grid(grid):
    """Show a list of strings as a grid, with even spacing."""
    n_cols = max(map(len, grid))
    width = len(str(n_cols-1))

    def format_width(value):
        fmt = '{{:>{}}}'.format(width)
        return fmt.format(value)

    header = map(format_width, ('', *range(n_cols)))
    print(*header)
    for i, s in enumerate(grid):
        row = map(format_width, (i, *s))
        print(*row)
```

Test run:

```
>>> print_grid(['.' * 5] * 5)
  0 1 2 3 4
0 . . . . .
1 . . . . .
2 . . . . .
3 . . . . .
4 . . . . .
>>> print_grid(['.' * 11] * 5)
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 0  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 2  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 3  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```